# Why does Eigen allocate a temporary to evaluate A.noalias() = B.transpose()*C in parallel?

Tags: c++, parallel-computing, eigen, memory-management

I wrote a program which iteratively transforms data using matrix multiplications. To minimize the number of large memory allocations, I use two roughly equal-sized `std::vector<double>`'s `data` and `temp_data` to store the current data and the new data respectively. For the matrix operations, I wrap each buffer into an `Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>`, called `data_matrix` and `temp_data_matrix` respectively. Then, I need to compute the following operation:

```
temp_data_matrix.noalias() = data_matrix.transpose()*factor;
```

where `factor` is simply an `Eigen::MatrixXd` which is much smaller than `data_matrix` or `temp_data_matrix`. Thanks to `.noalias()`, this line does not allocate any large temporaries normally. However, when multi-threading the program suddenly allocates a temporary (roughly) equal to the size of `temp_data`! In practice this can increase memory usage by around 50% so I'm curious about a few things:

- Why does this only happen when multi-threading? What algorithmic aspect requires a temporary buffer on top of the output buffer?
- Why does this not happen with the line `temp_data_matrix.noalias() = factor*data_matrix`? After all, my operation seems more cache-efficient: because we transpose `data_matrix`, we simply need to compute the scalar product of each pair of columns from `data_matrix` and `factor`, which should be fast considering both matrices are column-major. However, I'm not considering the effects of blocking here, which I know can be very important for performance.
- What would be the fastest way to implement the aforementioned line without allocating any temporaries of the order of `data` or `temp_data`? In case the parallel algorithm needs some "scratch space", can't it use `temp_data_matrix` for that? I don't care about copying `factor` because it's relatively small in practice. Right now the fastest solution seems to be to switch back to single-threading for this line, but I hope this can be improved. I tried using `lazyProduct` but this turned out to be much slower than the single-threaded solution.

**Appendix:** The observations above were made using Massif (valgrind) both in my original program and with the example code below. I compiled the example program using the command `g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -I /usr/include/eigen3 -fopenmp eigen_memory_test.cpp -o eigen_memory_test`.

````
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    bool parallel = (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "parallel") == 0);
    std::cout << "parallel: " << (parallel  ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
    bool lazyproduct = (argc > 2 && strcmp(argv[2], "lazyproduct") == 0);
    std::cout << "lazyproduct: " << (lazyproduct  ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
    bool test = true;
    
    // Initialize parallellism
    int threads = 4;
    Eigen::setNbThreads(threads);
    
    // Initialization and memory allocation
    size_t columns = 100000;
    std::vector<size_t> rows_per_step = {100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50};
    size_t steps = rows_per_step.size() - 1;
    std::vector<double> data(rows_per_step[0]*columns);
    std::vector<double> temp_data(rows_per_step[0]*columns);
    
    // Generate random data
    std::random_device rnd_device;
    std::mt19937 mersenne_engine {rnd_device()};
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(-1.0, 1.0);
    auto generator = std::bind(distribution, std::ref(mersenne_engine));
    std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), generator);
    
    // If testing, print first elements to verify later
    if (test)
        std::cout << "data[:3]: [" << data[0] << ", " << data[1] << ", " << data[2] << "]" << std::endl;
    
    // Process steps
    for (size_t step = 0; step < steps; step++) {
        
        size_t initial_rows = rows_per_step[step];
        size_t new_rows = rows_per_step[step + 1];
        
        // Choose factor
        Eigen::MatrixXd factor = (test ? 
            Eigen::MatrixXd(Eigen::MatrixXd::Identity(initial_rows, new_rows)) : 
            Eigen::MatrixXd(Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(initial_rows, new_rows))
        );
        
        // Transform data
        Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> data_matrix(data.data(), initial_rows, columns);
        Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> temp_data_matrix(temp_data.data(), columns, new_rows);
        if (!parallel)
            Eigen::setNbThreads(1);
        // In my real problem setting, the transpose in the following matrix multiplication is actually necessary
        if (lazyproduct)
            temp_data_matrix.noalias() = data_matrix.transpose().lazyProduct(factor);
        else
            temp_data_matrix.noalias() = data_matrix.transpose()*factor;
        Eigen::setNbThreads(threads);
        
        // Transpose back to original data
        // This doesn't happen in the real problem, but I put this here to keep this example simpler
        Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> transposed_data_matrix(data.data(), new_rows, columns);
        transposed_data_matrix.noalias() = temp_data_matrix.transpose();
        
    }
    
    // Print first elements to make sure matrix operations aren't optimized away
    std::cout << "data[:3]: [" << data[0] << ", " << data[1] << ", " << data[2] << "]" << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
    
}
```
````